# Why I keep getting wrong answer in this problem?

Tags: javascript

I need help with this logic problem in Uri Online Judge site: [image]

**The submitted code starts in "var n"**, I used the var lines to work with an example of input:

```js
var lines = ["400.00"]
/**
 * Code your solution here
 */
var n = parseFloat(lines[0]);

if (n <= 400.0) {
    console.log("Novo salario: " + Math.round(n * 1.15).toFixed(2));
    console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * 0.15).toFixed(2)); 
    console.log("Em percentual: 15 %");
} else if (n <= 800.0) {
    console.log("Novo salario: " + Math.round(n * 1.12).toFixed(2));
    console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * 0.12).toFixed(2)); 
    console.log("Em percentual: 12 %");
} else if (n <= 1200.0) {
    console.log("Novo salario: " + Math.round(n * 1.10).toFixed(2));
    console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * 0.10).toFixed(2)); 
    console.log("Em percentual: 10 %");
} else if (n <= 2000.0) {
    console.log("Novo salario: " + Math.round(n * 1.07).toFixed(2));
    console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * 0.07).toFixed(2)); 
    console.log("Em percentual: 7 %");
} else {
    console.log("Novo salario: " + Math.round(n * 1.04).toFixed(2));
    console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * 0.04).toFixed(2)); 
    console.log("Em percentual: 4 %");
}
```

when I submit this:
[image]
the console shows: Wrong answer (5%)
[image]

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? It's hard to say why this is considered a wrong answer if we don't know what the correct one should be.

Comment: `parseFloat("400.00") = 400`

Comment: @VLAZ If you have read, there is an input and ouput example, he have to create the script that get this output with this input

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama there wasn't input and output examples when I commented, so no need to be snarky

Comment: How does this code display `5%` as the wrong answer?  I do not see that in the code.  I see 15, 12, 10, 7, and 4 percent.

Comment: You are only generating output for half the input.

Comment: @Amy it's not the "5%" that it's wrong, that means my code is 5% of correct

Comment: @VLAZ You can click on the "edited x secs ago" and you will see that there has always been the input and output

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama Edits made immediately after when the question was submitted would not get separate entries in the edit history.

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama rapid edits that fall within some grace period are not shown in the history

Comment: This clearly is off topic: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @GabrielCunha I do not see where your console shows "wrong answer" either.  Please edit your question to clarify the results you're getting and the results you're expecting.

Comment: As with many online quiz sites, there is always the possibility the quality of the automated code review is sub-par. This seems like an issue to take up with the URI Online Judge - submit this question here: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/contact

Comment: DRY - the only difference in all the IF conditions is a single value (the rate) so just set that in your if conditions and do all the console.log repeated stuff after.

Comment: Because of the Round, for n = 800.05, +10% get 880.06,
800.05 * 1.10 give 880.0550000000001 then it will be rounded badly

Comment: Use the https://www.udebug.com/URI/1048 to try different values.  Your sample code only shows a very simple sample of "400" - the question itself shows "800.01" which if you were to use with *your code* would show that your code gives the wrong value.  You only get 5% because only 5% of your answers are correct given the sample.  Given the question itself, you immediately fail on 50% of the 2 samples provided, so not looking good from the bat.

Comment: Learn to step-through and debug your code.  In this case a simple open of the console and entering `Math.round(800.01 * 1.10)` will show that part not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem I see is you using `Math.round()` when the question does not mention any sort of rounding anywhere.

`Math.round(n * 1.12).toFixed(2)`

The example output shows `880.01` which is unobtainable with `Math.round` as it rounds to the nearest integer.

Edit: Here's concise way to write this without repeat yourself.

```
let factor; <-- // var factor; if no es6
if (n <= 400.0)
  factor = 0.15
else if (n <= 800.0)
  factor = 0.12
else if (n <= 1200.0)
  factor = 0.1
else if (n <= 2000.0)
  factor = 0.07
else
  factor = 0.04


console.log("Novo salario: " + (n * (1 + factor)).toFixed(2));
console.log("Reajuste ganho: " + (n * factor).toFixed(2)); 
console.log("Em percentual: " + factor * 100 + " %");
```